# How to resolve an IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, index-error

When I used the below code and an IndexError occurred. Where the details are shown below.

```
def get_code(seq): 
    return [x.split('.')[0] for x in seq if x]

all_codes = get_code(all_cats)
code_index = pd.Index(np.unique(all_codes))
dummy_frame = df(np.zeros((len(data), len(code_index))), index=data.index, columns=code_index)

for row, cat in zip(data.index, data.CATEGORY):
    codes = get_code(to_cat_list(cat))
    dummy_frame.iloc[row, codes] = 1

data = data.join(dummy_frame.add_prefix('category_'))

data.iloc[:, 10:15]
```

Below shown is the IndexError that occurred.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, the error occurs on the below line of code,

```
dummy_frame.iloc[row, codes] = 1
```

How can I resolve the above error to get the below information.

```
category_1  100 non-null values
category_1a 100 non-null values
category_1b 100 non-null values
category_1c 100 non-null values
category_1d 100 non-null values
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to say which line gives the error and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Mustafa Aydın the error occurs on this particular line  

dummy_frame.iloc[row, codes] = 1

Comment: Okay, what is `row` and `codes` before the error? Can you put `print("row:", row, "type:", type(row)); print("codes:", codes, "type:", type(codes))` above the line that gives error, and share the output in the question?

Comment: @MustafaAydın 

I hope you wanted the below output
`row: 0 type: <class 'int'>` 
`codes: ['1', '3'] type: <class 'list'>`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to write an answer below based on that, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iloc` is for integer-based indexing and passing `["1", "3"]` to it as the column indexer part is the reason why it fails. You can get the integer indexes i.e., positions of `["1", "3"]` in your frame's columns and pass that:

```
# these are integer positions of `codes` so that `iloc` works
codes_positions = dummy_frame.columns.get_indexer(codes)

# using `codes_positions` instead of `codes` directly
dummy_frame.iloc[row, codes_positions] = 1
```

There is also `loc` which looks for label-based indexing instead of integers. It seems that your row indexes are `0..N-1` so `loc` can work here, too:

```
# indexers remain the same but now using `loc`
dummy_frame.loc[row, codes] = 1
```

But please note that `loc` can be an alternative for `iloc` only when the index entries are integers (which seems so in your case). Otherwise, the first approach is more generic, less error-prone & clarifies the intent more.